# Axios не отлавливает ошибку (React + Flask)

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios

Имеется код, который пытается получить токен от сервера , передав ему логин и пароль.

```
  const login2 = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post('/api/login', { username, password })
      console.log(data)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }
```

При успешном ответе в консоль выводится результат (токен). Однако если сервер падает или не отвечает по таймауту, то никаких ошибок не отлавливается. Также ошибки не отлавливаются, если в axios-e делать запрос к некорректному endpoint-у, к примеру `/api/logAn`.

Если эти же манипуляции сделать через postman - он вернёт все корректные ошибки.

Как их отловить через axios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос отправился, отработал, вернулся ответ. К клиенту никаких претензий не вижу. Про какую ошибку речь? Вы предоставили очень мало данных. Что печатает в консоль ваш код при ошибках? Что показывается в postman?

Могу лишь предположить, что всего надо написать как-то вот так:

```
const { data, status } = await axios.post('/api/login', { username, password })
if (status !== 200) {
    throw data;
}
console.log(data);
```